# Kafka log lag negative

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, lag

I was writting a java program to consume messages from kafka.
Kafka version was 2.4.0.
I used spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASAE.
I was using cmak 3.0.0.5 to monitor Kakfa.

All seemed well when I first deployed the service. But as I killed the java program and restarted it again, I saw many of the lags of the topic partitions were negative. And I got no clue why
these lags could be negative. We got no requirements on message consistency, so I was not sure if the messages were lost or repeated consumed when I restarted the java program, but I guess they were not lost, but consumed repeatedly.